# Apache Access Control to IPs (X-Forwarded-For) or valid-user

Tags: linux, apache, f5

I used to block access to certain folder of my Apache server using valid-user or ip directive, like the following:

```
<Directory "/home/domain/public_html/secure">
    Require ip x.x.x.x
    Require ip y.y.y.y
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile "/home/domain/secure/pass"
    AuthName "Authentication Required"
    Require valid-user
    Satisfy Any
</Directory>
```

Now, I have placed my server behind an F5-BIGIP device which won't let me fully DNAT client's connections. The device is also behind a Linux server that serves as gateway with DNAT/SNAT rules hat are working accordingly. I can log client's IPs through X-Forwarded_For, though. But my Apache directives are not working anymore.

So my question is, is there any way I could use something like `Require X-Forwarded-For x.x.x.x`?

My Apache Version is:

```
[root@webserver1 ~]# apachectl -version
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   May 12 2016 1
```

0:27:23

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For x.x.x.x$ foo
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For y.y.y.y$ bar
...
Require env foo
Require env bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access headers as part of the require directive directly, so instead set an environment variable that matches, and use this as the test:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^123\.456\.78\.9" MyAllowedIPAddress
Require env MyAllowedIPAddress
```

Notes:

- *SetEnvIf* expects a Regular Expression as the test
- The environment variable name can be whatever you want (that doesn't clash!)
- *SetEnvIf* is evaluated after <if> directives, so will be confusing if you use both.  An alternative using <if> is below.

```
    <if "%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-For} == '123.456.78.9'">
          Require all granted
    </if>
    <else>
          Require all denied
    </else>
```